# How to access the instance of the main class from an anonymous in PHP 7?

Tags: php

I'm trying to access the instance of the class where it contains an anonymous as we do in Java, eg:

JAVA

```
class MyClass 
{
    private String prop = "test";

    public void test()
    {
        new Runnable() {

            public void run() 
            {
                // I can access MyClass.this from here
                System.out.println(MyClass.this.prop);
            }

        }.run();
    }
}
```

PHP 7

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $prop = "test";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class{

            public function run() 
            {
                // ???? MyClass::$prop ????
            }

        };
    }
}
```

How can I access the MyClass instance from within the anonymous?

Comment: you mean something like parent::prop ?http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php

Comment: You need to refer it as an StdClass then maybe use Reflection? You're mixing Java logic with PHP logic - that doesn't work because the scope doesn't reach. Unless you make the property static: it can be called using 'ClassName::$property' but has to be public.

Comment: @BenYitzhaki parent::$prop not work in php 7 anon classes

Comment: @KDOT that code is PHP 7

Comment: This is actually in [the documentation for anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php): _"Nesting an anonymous class within another class does not give it access to any private or protected methods or properties of that outer class. In order to use the outer class' protected properties or methods, the anonymous class can extend the outer class. To use the private properties of the outer class in the anonymous class, they must be passed through its constructor:"_

Comment: @Don'tPanic Unfortunately PHP has been trying to copy Java and others, but is still just a baby taking the first steps, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $prop = "test";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this){
            private $parentObj;
            public function __construct($parentObj)
            {
                $this->parentObj = $parentObj;
            }
            public function run() 
            {
                echo $this->parentObj->prop;
            }
        };
        $class->run();
    }
}

$x = new MyClass();
$x->test();
```

The key is to inject `$this` as a constructor parameter of the anonymous class.

Note: I've changed your `private $prop` to `public` so i wouldn't have to write a getter for it ;)

See if here: https://3v4l.org/IRhXd

Comment: Unfortunately PHP has been trying to copy Java and others, but is still just a baby taking the first steps, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! And don't worry, PHP will grow up... some day ;)

Comment: @Mystic PHP is a weaker typed language, if you want to use Java logic but stick to a PHP syntax then I suggest you look at Facebook's language, Hack.